# Does Apple accept apps with an embedded browser using UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store

Can you tell me if Apple accepts an application that opens an embedded browser with most of the functionality living on a web application on the internet?

I have read contradicting opinions on this, and I have even seen several apps that seem to use an embedded browser for the main functionality of the app. Still I couldn't confirm this.

This way we could correct problems on the application functionality on the server with no need to submit another version of the app, while keeping the ease of release through the app store and the home screen shortcut.
Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what your embedded browser does. Is it simply to provide an in-app browser for users to view web content without leaving your app? That's OK!

Comment: Users will access my web application only and won't leave the app.

Comment: That is a bad idea. Users can save a bookmark on their home screen instead.

Answer (score 0):

You say this is a bad idea because the user can save a bookmark on their home screen. This doesn't seem to me like a reason for something being a bad idea to me.  If this is the only drawback then I would say go ahead and do it.  Why should I care if someone wants to bookmark to my site?  The app will not work very well outside the app anyway.  If you have an actual logical reason why this is a bad idea instead of some emotional response then please bring it up.

I am doing this too in my application.  I am under the impression that as long as you are pointing to a secure site then it should be okay.  Please enlighten me: is there some good reason why Apple forces people to develop applications the hard way? A web application is hard enough without having to deal with some monolithic organisation imposing ridiculous rules on you.

Comment: Not sure who you are responding to. This post is from 2011, I completely forgot I had written this. Things have changed a lot since then, and I think I know the answer to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the exact quote from the guidelines, but I know that Cordova apps are allowed, and updating the web files dynamically without going through a new native app version is also allowed, as long as:
 * The updated code runs with the Safari Webkit engine (true for Cordova)
 * The main functionality of the app is not changed